# Insert multiple values into the same row for a single foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a project for a hotel reservation, and I want to insert multiple values into a column which is a foreign key in a table that has a primary key column but it's not possible to insert a duplicate key when it's primary and it's not possible to insert different values than the values that inserted in the main column that I used it as foreign key in this table, so what can I do?

**Clarification**

I have a table for reservation and another table for hotel services, there is a column in `[Reservation]` table which is the primary key (`ReservationID`) and there is a column in the `[Hotel_Services]` table that I used as a foreign key to the `[Reservation]` table which is (`ServiceID`).

What I want is to insert multiple service IDs into each reservation to indicates the services that each guest has added to his reservation, how can I do this?

Table #1: `Reservation`

```
`ReservationID` (primary key) e.g 10,20,30
```

Table #2: `Hotel_Services`

```
`ServiceID` (foreign key to `Reservations`) e.g 1, 2, 3
```

Desired result: add multiple service IDs into each reservation
e.g:

```
Reservation 10 has 1,2 services
Reservation 20 has 1,3 services
Reservation 30 has 2,3 services
```

Comment: Your database design is incorrect. You need a Reservation-Service linking table to allow a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: What i need is to know how can i add multiple services to each reservation not only one service?
because when i can't add multiple values into the foreign key while there is a Primary Key in the table i need to add multiple values into

Comment: i've mentioned two tables [Reservation], [Hotel Services] and i have a relation between them as i've put one column from Table2 as a Foreign key in Table1
so there is a relation between them but please clarify if i need to add another table and what should i add on it

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab

Comment: Thank you so much the link was so useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table `ReservationServices`, defined something like this:

```
create table ReservationServices (
    ReservationServiceId int identity primary key,
    ReservationId int not null references reservations(reservationid),
    ServiceId int not null references services(serviceid);
);
```

Then your data would look like:

```
ReservationServiceId     ReservationId    ServiceId
       1                     10               1 
       2                     10               2 
       3                     20               1 
       4                     20               3
       . . .
```

So, inserting a new service for a reservation is, well, as simple as inserting a new row in this table.